# Displaying a cv2 image onto Tkinter GUI - "TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to replicate the following code to output a cv2 image onto a GUI :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Tkinter 
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

# Load an color image
img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

#Rearrang the color channel
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))

# A root window for displaying objects
root = Tkinter.Tk()  

# Convert the Image object into a TkPhoto object
im = Image.fromarray(img)
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im) 

# Put it in the display window
Tkinter.Label(root, image=imgtk).pack() 

root.mainloop() # Start the GUI
```

however on trying to execute this, I end up with the following error:

```
TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

In my understanding it is looking for something name pyimage1, I have searched by code multiple times and there is nothing by that name, unless this is a module I am missing. 
The output is essentially just a blank GUI with no image being displayed accompanied by the error in my terminal. 
Any guidance on how to proceed will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
```

to

```
root = Toplevel
```

.. Just a guess let me know if it works.